# I can't fill the alpha angle with blue

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I'm trying to fill the angle between A,B,C with blue color but it doesn't fill even though I write the code.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\tkzDefPoint(-8,4){A},
\tkzDefPoint(-7.07,10.43){B},
\tkzDefPoint(1.1,4.01){C},
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\tkzLabelSegment[left,font=\footnotesize](A,B){$6,5$}
\tkzLabelSegment[below,font=\footnotesize](A,C){$9,1$}
\tkzLabelSegment[right,font=\footnotesize](B,C){$10,4$}
\draw[thick,black](-8,4)--(-7.08,10.43)--(1.1,4.01)--cycle;
\tkzMarkAngle[fill= blue!40,size=1.4cm,opacity=.5](A,B,C)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.8](A,B,C){$\alpha$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\tkzDefPoint(-8,4){A},
\tkzDefPoint(-7.07,10.43){B},
\tkzDefPoint(1.1,4.01){C},
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\tkzLabelSegment[left,font=\footnotesize](A,B){$6,5$}
\tkzLabelSegment[below,font=\footnotesize](A,C){$9,1$}
\tkzLabelSegment[right,font=\footnotesize](B,C){$10,4$}
\draw[thick,black](-8,4)--(-7.08,10.43)--(1.1,4.01)--cycle;
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1.4cm,opacity=.5](A,B,C)
\tkzFillAngle[fill= blue!40,size=1.4cm,opacity=.5](A,B,C)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.8](A,B,C){$\alpha$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Triangle with ABC angle filled]

Comment: Doesn’t look blue to me.

Comment: Yes, i realized my mistake. You are right thank you sir

Comment: I would definitely fill the angle before drawing the triangle and the points, to avoid the coloring being on the first layer.

Answer (score 2):

Since  you load a `pstricks` module, here is a short code to do it with `pst-eucl`, which defines a command to plot a triangle, given a vertex and the lengths of the three sides (`\pstTriangleSSS`):

```
 \documentclass[border=6pt, svgnames]{standalone}
 \usepackage{pst-eucl}%

\begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.5)(9, 7)%
    \psset{linejoin=1}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle=-90](0,0){A}
    \pstTriangleSSS[PosAngle={-90,90}]{A}(10.4, 6.5, 9.1){C}{B}
    \pstMarkAngle[LabelSep=0.5, MarkAngleRadius=0.8, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=Lavender, linewidth=0.4pt] {A}{B}{C}{$\alpha$}
    \psset{labelsep=2pt,nrot=:U}
    \pcline(A)(B)\naput{6,5}
    \pcline(B)(C)\naput{10,4}
    \pcline(A)(C)\nbput{9,1}
    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help